# Write to binary performance numpy.ndarray.tofile vs numpy.ndarray.tobytes vs C++ file.write

Tags: c++, numpy, binaryfiles, fstream

I'm trying to write to disk some large arrays. I've tested 3 options;
2 in Python:

```
    import timeit
    import numpy as np

    # N=800 generates files about 4GB
    N=800
    compute_start=timeit.default_timer()

    vals = np.sqrt((np.arange(N)**2)[:,None,None]+(np.arange(N)**2)[None,:,None]+(np.arange(N)**2)[None,None,:])

    compute_end=timeit.default_timer()
    print("Compute time: ",compute_end-compute_start)

    tofile_start=timeit.default_timer()
    for i in range(2):
       f = open("out.bin", "wb")
       vals.tofile(f)
       f.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    tofile_end=timeit.default_timer()
    print("tofile time: ",tofile_end-tofile_start)

    tobytes_start=timeit.default_timer()
    for i in range(2):
       f = open("out.bin", "wb")
       f.write(vals.tobytes())
       f.close()
    tobytes_end=timeit.default_timer()
    print("tobytes time: ",tobytes_end-tobytes_start)
```

And for C++ (compiled with `g++ -O3`

```
#include<chrono>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
int main(){
   std::vector<double> q(800*800*800, 3.14);

   auto dump_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
   
   for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
      std::ofstream outfile("out.bin",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
      outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&q[0]), q.size()*sizeof(double));
      outfile.close();
   }   

   auto dump_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

   std::printf("Dump time: %12.3f\n",(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(dump_end - dump_start).count())/1000000.0);

   return 0;
}
```

Times reported are 16 seconds for `tofile`, 39 seconds for `tobyte` and 34 for `write`. Any ideas on why they should be so different? Especially the two Numpy cases; the docs say that `numpy.ndarray.tofile()` is equivalent to `file.write(numpy.ndarray.tobytes()).`

Thank you~

Comment: I would expext that the explicit  tobytes call is slower, because it must copy the data in RAM and than pass it back to the write function.

Comment: Have the file created by C++ and Python the same size?

Comment: @gerum, is there any way to imitate what `tofile` does in c++?
Yes, both file sizes are 3.9G

Comment: Just a guess, but can you try to save the more complex data within your C++ code, something that is not just the same number.

Comment: And an addition hint: import in c++, it is called include there.

Comment: I've tried writing random numbers as well in the c++ code, doesn't change anything. Thanks for the comments!! And good catch; I've edited my question.

Comment: Try what happens if you increase or decrease the number of iterations, stays the time ratio constant?

Answer (score 0):

I've been bothered by the speed of `numpy.ndarray.tofile()` when writing large data sets (16 GB) to raw binary files as well lately, and here's what helped in my case (running on Windows 10), though I don't understand why:

- use `numpy.ndarray.flatten().tofile()`, assuming you're not bothered by the structure when writing binary files
- instead of overwriting an existing file, delete it first and then write the file

So with your variable names, by using this this code in my case:

```
import numpy
import os

if os.path.exists("out.bin"):
   os.remove("out.bin")
vals.flatten().tofile("out.bin", sep='', format='<H')
```

the writing speed increased from around 60 MB/s to almost 200 MB/s (which is still below the limit of the SSD). However, the writing speed isn't constant and will sometimes drop. It might still be helpful I hope.